# How to use redis cloud for codeigniter session on heroku

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, heroku, redis

i am new on heroku. I just install redis cloud on heroku. I am using codeigniter to develop my application, i want to understand how can i handle session on redis server i search on Google so finally i got this link [A CodeIgniter library to interact with Redis](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis) is this enough to handle session on redis or something i have to do more please help me guys .

If this github library is useful then how can i use this library for session management

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys this [A CodeIgniter library to interact with Redis](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis) this work for me....:)

this library also handle session on redis heroku....

thax to all of u............